# Full Outer Join not returning unmatched join field values SQL SERVER 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, outer-join

I use the below code to calculate the earned premium by coverage (automobile) for a given month which in this case is September. What the code is doing is Subtracting the total earned premium all time up to September 30 minus the total earned premium all time up to August 31 in order to return the premium earned during the month of September alone.

The Results look something like this:

```
eprem        coveragecode  
0.0211       AD  
277970.8291  BI  
245700.6741  COLL  
86997.5694   COMP  
85.0083      CustomParts  
848.7873     Death  
0.00         ECL  
0.00         GPIP  
692.3802     Income  
2410.5513    MED  
267670.1099  PD  
387628.504   PIP  
26.8767      PU  
11736.2762   Rental  
4304.3367    Towing   
4211.2574    UIMBI  
19804.8964   UMBI  
15145.3211   UMPD
```

---

When I add up the premium for all the coverages i get 1325233.399 which is the correct exact amount of premium earned for the month of september.

Now what I am trying to do is to also add the zipcode field in the result. If i run the below code without the zipcode column specified anywhere in the code then I get the above result which is correct but when i add the zipcode column i return thousands of rows which is expected but when i add up the total premium i am getting 1323608.401 instead of the 1325233.399  which is the correct total. I believe what is happening is that there are certain coverage & zip code combinations (which is what i joined my 2 derived tables on) that exist in one month (derived table) and note in the other. I get different amount of rows returned when i do a right join as to when i do a left join but when i add up all the premiums it always equals to 1323608.401 instead of 1325233.399 . I thought the solution to my problem would be to use a full outter join and thus return all results (even those unmatching) so that then my total premium would add up to the 1325233.399 but i am still only getting 1323608.401  no matter what type of join i try to use. Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here??? Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
    SELECT   sept.eprem-aug.eprem as eprem , sept.coveragecode, zipcode 
from

(select 
SUM(EarnedPremium) AS eprem,coveragecode, evaluationdate, zipcode                       
FROM         dbo.StatRateSummary                            
where evaluationdate = '09-30-2011' 
and decpagetypecode != 'x'
GROUP BY evaluationdate ,coveragecode, zipcode

) as sept full outer join 

(select 
SUM(EarnedPremium) AS eprem,coveragecode, evaluationdate, zipcode                       
FROM         dbo.StatRateSummary                            
where evaluationdate = CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,'09-30-2011'),0)), 102)  
and decpagetypecode != 'x'
GROUP BY evaluationdate ,coveragecode, zipcode

) as aug on sept.coveragecode = aug.coveragecode and sept.zipcode = aug.zipcode
where sept.coveragecode is not null and sept.coveragecode <> ''
order by coveragecode, sept.evaluationdate
```

Comment: what data type is EarnedPremium?

Comment: it's a "money" data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was change the first line of code to convert any null premium value to 0.

```
SELECT   isnull(sept.eprem,0)-isnull(aug.eprem,0) as eprem , sept.coveragecode, zipcode 
from

(select 
SUM(EarnedPremium) AS eprem,coveragecode, evaluationdate, zipcode                       
FROM         dbo.StatRateSummary                            
where evaluationdate = '09-30-2011' 
and decpagetypecode != 'x'
GROUP BY evaluationdate ,coveragecode, zipcode

) as sept full outer join 

(select 
SUM(EarnedPremium) AS eprem,coveragecode, evaluationdate, zipcode                       
FROM         dbo.StatRateSummary                            
where evaluationdate = CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,'09-30-2011'),0)), 102)  
and decpagetypecode != 'x'
GROUP BY evaluationdate ,coveragecode, zipcode

) as aug on sept.coveragecode = aug.coveragecode and sept.zipcode = aug.zipcode
where sept.coveragecode is not null and sept.coveragecode <> ''
order by coveragecode, sept.evaluationdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Your FULL OUTER JOIN condition should look like this:

```
SELECT   sept.eprem-aug.eprem as eprem , sept.coveragecode, zipcode 
from

(select 
SUM(EarnedPremium) AS eprem,coveragecode, evaluationdate, zipcode                       
FROM         dbo.StatRateSummary                            
where evaluationdate = '09-30-2011' 
and decpagetypecode != 'x'
-- Migrated WHERE Condition
AND COALESCE(eprem.coveragecode, '') > ''
GROUP BY evaluationdate ,coveragecode, zipcode

) as sept FULL OUTER join 

(select 
SUM(EarnedPremium) AS eprem,coveragecode, evaluationdate, zipcode                       
FROM         dbo.StatRateSummary                            
where evaluationdate = CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,'09-30-2011'),0)), 102)  
and decpagetypecode != 'x'
GROUP BY evaluationdate ,coveragecode, zipcode

) as aug on sept.coveragecode = aug.coveragecode and sept.zipcode = aug.zipcode
/*
|| See SEPT derived table for elimination of NULL and '' coverage codes
|| where sept.coveragecode is not null and sept.coveragecode <> ''
*/
order by coveragecode, sept.evaluationdate
```

One thing to consider is that when you are using an `OUTER JOIN` the WHERE criteria ***may*** cause the optimizer to re-write the JOIN as an `INNER JOIN` instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the reply. I just tried the code and at first i got an error message saying the Zipcode was an ambiguous column name so i chose to use sept.zipcode and then I tried aug.zipcode and then i tried both of them in the select statement and all of the results are still giving me a total premium of 1323608.401 instead of the 1325233.399 amount which is the correct earned premium amount for september. The code that i am running to obtain the 1325233.399 number is the same code in my original question but without any references to the zipcode column anywhere in the code.

Comment: Its so strange that no matter what type of join i use i keep getting the 1323608.401 total...

Comment: Realized I left the ZIPCODE in the ON clause. What if you remove that and resubmit the query?

Comment: i removed ZIPCODE from the ON clause and the query returned millions of records and the premium total was -61210318.62. Using your orignial code with the ZIPCODE in the ON clause the total premium returned of 1323608.401 is only off by around $2,000.

Comment: I just figured out what was wrong. In the first line of my code in the select statement I was subtracting the different eprem values but since i was doing a full outer join there were times when sept.eprem or aug.eprem was null so instead of a normal computation of lets say $25 - $10= $15 I would get something like $25 - NULL = NULL instead of $25 - NULL = $25. All i need to do now is write an IF or CASE statement or use one of those replace functions so that if either aug.eprem or sept.eprem is NULL then make it equal to $0 so the eprem calculation can be preformed correctly.